# Error: Value "PONG" or "OK" in the redis cache

Tags: redis

I use the following code in the server , but I got an error `cacheVal` is "PONG" or "OK" at sometimes ,  the following code get `cacheVal` is right in the most cases .

```
Jedis sjedis = getJedis();
String cacheVal = sjedis.get(key);
```

Comment: We need more information as to what your application is doing and what is the whole code. Redis never returns any information which is not stored. `OK` is always returned as a response but you don't get in when using JEDIS unless you specifically stored `OK` as a string against that key

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI - I was able to replicate and resolve this issue:

The reason why this was happening in the first place is because I was using `try-with-resource` incorrectly - basically returning jedis connection in try.

- If close() was called after I was done with jedis connection (which was mostly the case as it was really fast) I'd get no exception.
- But if close() was invoked while using the returned jedis connection I'd get exception - {socket closed or PONG or OK} (and note I had testOnBorrow=true)

Below I am listing correct and incorrect way to use jedisPool

Incorrect way to use jedisPool:

    `try (Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource()) {
        return jedis;
    } catch (JedisConnectionException ex) {
        //exception handling
    }`

Correct Way to use jedisPool:

    `try (Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource()) {
        //complete all the work you need to do with jedis
        //you may return computed value or anything else but not jedis connection
    } catch (JedisConnectionException ex) {
        //exception handling
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Were you by any chance able to resolve this or work around this?

I faced the exact same problem and this occurs about 1% of the time.

`jedis.get(key)` literally returns string "PONG" or "OK". Same call in the next instance returns expected value.

I am using jedisPool with mostly all default connection pool settings but added only `testOnBorrow=true` (which I know will play ping/pong with redis to validate connection it is holding on to and I need this reliability).

```
public Jedis getConnection() {
        try (Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource()) {
            return jedis;
        } catch (JedisConnectionException ex) {
            String errorMessage = String.format(REDIS_CONNECTION_ERROR_MESSAGE, redisHost, redisPort);
            LOGGER.error(errorMessage, ex);
            throw new JedisConnectionException(errorMessage, ex);
        }
    }
```

And I also noticed that when I set `testOnBorrow=false` the value "PONG" is not returned but "OK" is still returned.

I also increased the `maxTotal=50K`, `maxIdle=25K`, `blockOnExhausted=false` thinking maybe it is due to multiple client threads and this could be related to concurrent clients trying to access the same key at the same time but that did not help.

I tried upgrading to latest jedis (v2.8.1) and redis (v3.2.1) but I was able to replicate this, that too on local redis instance (so latency is not an issue).

Please let me know if you have any clarifying questions and I can provide more details.

Thoughts..?